# Samba Winbind not working in Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, samba, active-directory, kerberos

I am setting up a new samba environment based on Debian Jessie.
Installation of PDC was succesfully and Windows clients were able to join. Have a problem at joining the Linux clients.

I was following the tutorial [SAMBA Share with Active Directory Login](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/SAMBA_Share_with_Active_Directory_Login_on_Ubuntu_12.04.html) but could not complete. I fail at "chgrp -R "Domain Users" /share, because he will not find the group "chgrp: invalid group: ???domain users???"
wbinfo -u is WORKING
getent passwd is WORKING and shows domain accounts
BUT getent passwd (DOMAINUSER) will not show up anything.

I will paste my smb.conf, nsswitch.conf and krb5.conf, please help me :(

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
    workgroup = x
    security = ads
    realm = x.LOCAL
    domain master = no
    local master = no
    preferred master = no
    printcap name = /etc/printcap
    load printers = no
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap config * : range = 10001-20000
    idmap config x : schema_mode = rfc2307
    idmap config x : backend = rid
    idmap config x : range = 500-20000
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind use default domain = yes
    winbind nested groups = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    winbind offline logon = true
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    client use spnego = yes
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
    log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
    log level = 2
```

**/etc/krb5.conf**

```
    [libdefaults]
        ticket_lifetime = 24h
        default_realm = x.LOCAL
        forwardable = true

[realms]
        x.LOCAL = {
                       kdc = pdc.fqdn
                       default_domain = x.local
                       }

[domain_realm]
        .x.local = x.LOCAL
        x.local = x.LOCAL

[kdc]
        profile = /etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

[appdefaults]
        pam = {
            debug = false
            ticket_lifetime = 36000
            renew_lifetime = 36000
            forwardable = tru
            krb4_convert = false
            }

[logging]
        kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
        admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmin.log
        default = FILE:/var/log/krb5lib.log
```

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
passwd:         files winbind
group:          files winbind
shadow:         files winbind
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns wins
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

any ideas? Do you need more log files?

Comment: You must install libpam-winbind and libnss-winbind. Please check that in your /etc/resolv.conf your (samba4) AD domain is set as search parameter and your domaincontroller as nameserver. You already have winbind in /etc/nsswitch.conf. Do pam-auth-update and net ads join -Uadministrator again and try service winbind restart (or even a reboot, sometimes things get stuck) and getent passwd again.

Answer (score 0):

according to your error message, there may not be a group "Domain Users" on your system, do a

```
$ grep "Domain Users" /etc/group
```

possibly you need to do:

```
# addgroup "Domain Users" (as root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the setup guide at http://thepullen.net/wp/2013/03/using-winbind-to-resolve-active-directory-accounts-in-debian/. Also make sure libnss-winbind is installed.

You can test winbind itself with 'wbinfo -u' (should return a huge list of all your domain users).

the command 'id xxxx' will try to find info about just user xxx using the system/nsswitch.conf configuration. Between those you should be able to figure out where the problem is.